# How to specify maximum download size?

Tags: java, httpclient

Apart from maximum redirects, and such how can the maximum download size of a URL be specified for a Httpclient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get `Content-Length` back, it is optional; you have to download the resource as a stream and keep track of how many bytes you have downloaded manually yourself. That is just the way HTTP works.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no HTTP header to tell the server the max response size. You can check the `Content-Length` of the response and return immediately if it's too large. If it's not specified (it can even by unknown on the server side) your only option is to start downloading it. Don't worry: when you call `HttpClient.execute().getEntity()` the content **is not entirely downloaded anywhere**. An [`HttpEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html) can be streamed and buffered, meaning that it's not entirely kept in memory or saved on disk as soon as you call `execute()`

[You can explore the sources yourself](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRequestDirector.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up solving the problem, as per Jarrod's answer:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(url));
response = client.execute(request);
BufferedReader in;

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String line = "";

char buffer[] = new char[1024];

int totalReadSize = 0, currentRead=0;
while ((currentRead = in.read(buffer,0,buffer.length)) != -1)
{
    totalReadSize += currentRead;
    line = new String(buffer);
    sb.append(line);
    if (totalReadSize > MAX_DOWNLOAD_SIZE)
    {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        throw new Exception("File too large");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should specify the Charset of the InputStreamReader (taken from the Content-Type header I guess)